# keywords and description for front-page of drupal 7 site

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I managed to set page titles with the "Page Titles" module and keywords and description with the "Meta Tags (Quick)" plugin, however it seems like there is currently no way of having custom keywords/description for the front-page. Does anybody knows of a work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module

It'll allow you to set keywords and descriptions to your site, and you can override those settings to be different for the front page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the meta tags to a view or a node and set the path of the node or view as the frontpage in the site information configuration

Comment: But I already have hardcoded so much in page--front.tpl.php, wouldn't this mess with that?

Comment: No, this is just related to the $content variable, as long as you have that you're fine. In fact you can re-create the default Drupal homepage with Views. Just enable the frontpage view that comes with Views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Path-Based Metatags option in [Meta tags quick](https://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) module, enable module and go to front page, you will see Path-Based Metatags option...when you click on the option, you can fill in the fields that you want, you can also set the fields that you want to display (admin/config/search/metatags_quick)...